# Use of locale-specific grouping separator in java Formatter

Tags: java, formatting, scjp

I'm studying for SCJP, and my book (Sierra's) says about the Formatter class that I can use the flag "," to use locale-specific grouping separator. If I understand well, this line of code:

```
System.out.printf("%2$,f + %1$,f", 123.7, 456.2);
```

should produce:

```
456,200000 + 123,700000
```

with comma, but it's actually producing:

```
456.200000 + 123.700000
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  System.out.printf("%2$,f + %1$,f", 1232.7, 4562343.2);
```

will give you

```
4,562,343.200000 + 1,232.700000
```

The numbers you are using for your example are less than 1000 and do not need thousand separators.

Comment: If you use a locale that needs , as a decimal separator you will get it correctly.